# How to handle 503 responses within an AWS Target Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm using an AWS Target Group with a load balancer to service requests.  When new instances are added to the Target Group for a period of time they return 503 as the Java process running on the instance is starting up.

If I have (as an example) 4 instances in the target group and am using round robin this causes every 4th request to fail.

Ideally, if a server is returning 503 I'd like the request to get transparently retried to another instance in the group such that a success response gets returned to the caller if possible.

What's the best way to handle a slow starting server making my target group wonky because it is returning 503s during start up?  Can this be handled so that external traffic is unaware that requests are retried behind the scenes?

I looked within AWS and found the attribute `Slow start duration` The description makes it sound as though this causes a slow ramp up of traffic to the new instance.  Since I know my server will be returning 503s for around 60s, I would prefer no traffic get sent to that instance.

A timeout potentially has the ability to mask this problem, though just retrying a 503 seems like a better solution, imho.

Comment: It sounds like your healthcheck is pointing to a static instead of a dynamic file so ALB doesnt know java isnt ready? If the instance health check fails, it shouldn't receive any traffic (so long as there are other healthy instances available). There are options to delay starting health checks, and how many successes are required to declare the instance healthy and ready to serve traffic. (Please ensure you understand the implications of changing the healthchecks behavior for your app and scenario)

Comment: Agree with@MisterSmith. On slow starting applications I typically increase the `Interval` which is time between health checks of an individual target. This used in combination with `Unhealthy threshold` which is the the number of consecutive health check failures required before considering a target unhealthy can allow you to find a sweet spot with regards to how long your EC2 instances take to respond. For example 3x `Unhealthy threshold` multiplied by 60 second `Interval` would give them 3mins.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is taking time to start then you can set Slow start duration time according to your application start time.

**slow_start.duration_seconds** >> The time period, in seconds, during which the load balancer sends a newly registered target a linearly increasing share of the traffic to the target group.

Reference link:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html